# Does "¿Qué llevas a cada uno?" mean what do you bring or what do you wear or something else?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

In the following text:

> ¿A qué eventos especiales te gusta asistir? Escribe sobre dos. ¿Qué llevas a cada uno?

Does "¿Qué llevas a cada uno?" mean what do you bring or what do you wear or something else?

Comment: Can you give some context on where did you see this text? Otherwise it is difficult to guess.

Comment: Hard to say. I would bet for "bring", if it were "wear" the question would be _¿qué llevas puesto...?_.

Comment: Closing since we need more details. Please [edit] your question to show them; then we will be able to reopen the question to better assist you. Thanks!